# key=lambda (user_id, num_friends): num_friends

Tags: python, sorting, lambda

I tried to run this code

```
#create a list (user_id, number_of_friends)
num_friends_by_id = [(user["id"], number_of_friends(user))
for user in users]
sorted(num_friends_by_id, # get it sorted
key=lambda (user_id, num_friends): num_friends, # by num_friends
reverse=True) # largest to smallest
# each pair is (user_id, num_friends)
# [(1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3), (5, 3), (8, 3),# (0, 2), (4, 2), (6, 2), (7, 2), (9, 1)]
```

But it always gives me this error

```
File "C:/Users/jaide/Desktop/Ramdom.ipynb", line 41
    key=lambda (user_id, num_friends): num_friends, # by num_friends
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any help?

Comment: you probably just need `lambda user_id, num_friends: num_friends` but that isn't a valid key function, which will only be passed a single argument, so you're trading a SyntaxError for an eventual runtime error

Comment: Python 2 allowed you to unpack a sequence argument; Python 3 dropped it (IIRC, because it was deemed not worth the complexity it added to the parser).

Comment: Not worth the complexity it added to introspection, too.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for a lambda function is: `lambda arguments : expression`. So in your code, the syntax is wrong, because of the brackets.

The other mistake is that, the `key` argument in `sorted` function takes a callable, or lambda with a SINGLE argument. What you have done is tried to unpack the value of the element passed to the lambda and then sort it by the second argument. But you can't perform unpacking in the arguments of the lambda function. Instead, as we know that the each element in your list is a tuple with the first element being user_id and the second being num_friends, we can access the second element of each tuple by the index `1` (zero indexing). And by using this we can sort the list by the num_friends:

```py
sorted(num_friends_by_id, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

Comment: Your argument in the first paragraph sounds like `lambda user_id, num_friends: expression` is also wrong syntax, because of the comma.

Comment: lambda functions can have multiple arguments. In the case of the `key` argument for the `sorted` function, the lambda function only requires one argument. Which I have specified in the second section...